# Why is my generic type inferred wrong [typescript]

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference

I have a function `function createConfig<T>(schema: Schema<T>, opts?: ConfigOptions): Config<T>` and T is inferred by providing a Schema object.

```
const config = createConfig({
    testProp: {
        default: true,
        optional: true
    },
});
```

However T is inferred as

```
{testProp: {default: {valueOf}, optional: {valueOf}}}
```

instead of

```
{testProp: {default: booelan, optional: boolean}}
```

The big question for me is why this happens and how can fix this behaviour?

The Schema is defined as

```
export interface SchemaObj<T> {
    default: T | null;
    transformer?: (val: unknown) => T;
    env?: string;
    maskValueInToString?: boolean;
    description?: string;
    optional?: boolean;
}

export type Schema<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends { default: infer U } ? SchemaObj<U> : Schema<T[P]>;
};
```

To see the full code, head over to https://github.com/nidomiro/ts-tools/tree/1a61f8aa195060ac135390a6a1bcc2ab148474ca/packages/config-helper/src/lib

Comment: please provide a minimal example

Comment: What is missing in the content above to count as a minimal example?